# R- split histogram according to factor level

Tags: r, histogram, levels

This is my data:

```
type<-rep(c(0,1),100) 
diff<-rnorm(100)
data<-data.frame(type,diff)
```

If I want to plot historgram of `diff`, I do this:

```
hist(data$diff)
```

But what I want to do to split my histogram according to `type`. I could do this:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(data$diff[data$type==0])
hist(data$diff[data$type==1])
```

But what this is giving me are two different histograms side by side. What I want to do is produce a single histogram with `diff` of `0` at one side and `diff`of `1` at other side. Something like this with bars as continuous without the breaks or border in between. This presumably would mean the axis will be split into two for each factor. 
 [image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data,aes(x=diff))+geom_histogram()+facet_grid(~type)+theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can also put them on the same plot by "dodging" them:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=diff,group=type,fill=type))+
  geom_histogram(position="dodge",binwidth=0.25)+theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want them to overlap, the position has to be `position="identity"`

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=diff,group=type,fill=type))+
  geom_histogram(position="identity",alpha=0.5,binwidth=0.25)+theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want them to look like it does in the first one but without the border, you have to hack it a little:

```
data$diff[data$type==1] <- data$diff[data$type==1] + 6

ggplot(data,aes(x=diff,group=type,fill=type))+
  geom_histogram(position="identity",alpha=0.5,binwidth=0.25)+theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-2:2,4:8),labels=c(-2:2,-2:2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sam. I could produce this plot. But I was looking to merge these two. Basically the same ones without the borders separating them in between.

Answer (score 15):

That plot was made using the lattice package

```
set.seed(1)
type<-rep(c(0,1),100) 
diff<-rnorm(100)
data<-data.frame(type,diff)


library('lattice')
histogram(~ diff | type, data = data)
```

[image]

here is how you can do it in base graphics

```
## first plot - left half of x-axis, right margin set to 0 lines
par(fig = c(0, .5, 0, 1), mar = c(5,4,3,0))
hist(data$diff[data$type==0], ann = FALSE, las = 1)

## second plot - right half of x-axis, left margin set to 0 lines
par(fig = c(.5, 1, 0, 1), mar = c(5,0,3,2), new = TRUE)
hist(data$diff[data$type==1], ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)
axis(1)
axis(2, lwd.ticks = 0, labels = FALSE)

title(main = 'Histogram', xlab = 'x label', outer = TRUE, line = -2)
```

[image]