# creating histogram with grouping variable

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to create one diagram with three histograms one beneath the other. The data is like this one:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
A  rt
a1 825
a1 792
a1 840
a2 997
a2 902
a2 786
a3 888
a3 634
a3 783
")
```

With one grouping variable and the numeric variable reaction time. My task is to create three histograms for each grouping condition.

Here is a link how it is supposed to look in the end. Here the grouping variable is divided in "Simple", "Go/NoGo" and "Choice". As you can see it is not sufficient to create three histograms for each condition and put it under each other.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWTCS.png)

I tried doing it like this:

```
hist(dat$rt~dat$A,seq(600,1000,100),freq=T)
```

but R returns the error message, that x has to be numerical.

I'm not allowed to use ggplot for this exercise, I'm not allowed to load any additional packages.

Maybe somebody can help me out! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34046049/11570343)

Comment: Use this
`par(mfrow = c(3, 1))`
`hist(dat$rt[dat$A=="a1"],freq=T)`
`hist(dat$rt[dat$A=="a2"],freq=T)`
`hist(dat$rt[dat$A=="a3"],freq=T)`

Comment: thank you, the problem is then it just gives me three separate histograms when I need one with the three included

Comment: This should work `ggplot(dat, aes(rt, fill = factor(A)))+
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, aes(y = ..density..), position = 'identity')`